# systemctl doesnt work in Ubuntu 22.04 container

Tags: linux, ubuntu, systemctl

```
$ docker run -it --name systemd-tutorial ubuntu
root@306c0deb6960:~# systemctl
bash: systemctl: command not found
```

why??

The systemctl utility, which is available by default in Ubuntu, can be used to list services in Ubuntu 22.04 using the command “systemctl –no-pager”.

my version:

```
root@306c0deb6960:~# cat /etc/*-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=22.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=jammy
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS"
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why?

Containers, typically used for single -service jobs, typically come without the full systemd suite of service management, which would have trouble running without access to the system dbus, anyway. So, this is kind of expected.